# adapter getFilter not filtering

Tags: java, android

I'm at a loss on this one, after reading several posts I still have no clue what to do with my current situation. But when I filter my Cursor Adapter the list will not update or filter anything, it is like nothing happens at all.

here is the activity where i view a list of clients

```
public class ViewClientActivity extends Activity
{

EditText inputSearch;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewclient_activity);

    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_view);

    DBHandler handler = new DBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = handler.getReadableDatabase();
    final Cursor ClientCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM clients", null);
    final ListView allClients = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.allClients);
    final ClientCursorAdapter clientAdapter = new ClientCursorAdapter(this, ClientCursor);

    allClients.setAdapter(clientAdapter);



    allClients.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Cursor cur = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            int clientIdint = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            String clientId = Integer.toString(clientIdint);
            Intent AddClientIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddClientActivity.class);
            AddClientIntent.putExtra("CLIENT_IDINT", clientIdint);
            AddClientIntent.putExtra("CLIENT_ID", clientId);
            startActivity(AddClientIntent);
        }
    });

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
        {
            // When user changed the Text
            clientAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());
            allClients.setAdapter(clientAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

}
}
```

and here is my cursor class

```
public class ClientCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{

public ClientCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
}

// The newView method is used to inflate a new view and return it,
// you don't bind any data to the view at this point.
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.display_client_row, parent, false);
}

// The bindView method is used to bind all data to a given view
// such as setting the text on a TextView.
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // Find fields to populate in inflated template
    TextView txtViewName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtViewName);
    TextView txtViewAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtViewAddress);
    TextView txtViewPhoneNum = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtViewPhoneNum);
    // Extract properties from cursor
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
    String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
    String homenum = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("homenum"));
    String cellnum = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("cellnum"));
    String worknum = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("worknum"));
    // Populate fields with extracted properties
    txtViewName.setText(name);
    txtViewAddress.setText(address);

    if (!cellnum.equals("") && !cellnum.equalsIgnoreCase("cell phone"))
    {
        txtViewPhoneNum.setText(String.valueOf(cellnum));
    }
    else if (!homenum.equals("") && !homenum.equalsIgnoreCase("home phone"))
    {
        txtViewPhoneNum.setText(String.valueOf(homenum));
    }
    else if (!worknum.equals("") && !worknum.equalsIgnoreCase("work phone"))
    {
        txtViewPhoneNum.setText(String.valueOf(worknum));
    }
    else
    {
        txtViewPhoneNum.setText("No phone listed.");
    }

}

}
```

thanks for your time and let me know if you need any other information!

Comment: `addTextChangedListener` will not directly work with `CursorAdapter`

Comment: so ill have to make a new adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter `CursorAdapter` or `SimpleCursorAdapter` you have to use `clientAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider` than you can filter your content.

```
  clientAdapter .setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
   public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
  //your code here
    }

 });
```

You can see here for more detailed explanation: [How to set Filter to ListView with CursorAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026679/how-to-set-filter-to-listview-with-cursoradapter)
Also you don't have to setup adapter twice remove `allClients.setAdapter(clientAdapter);` from your `addTextChangedListener` method. If needed you can call `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: that would still go inside the onTextChanged method correct?

Comment: thanks for the help. i dont have it running yet but it is what i need to do!