# SearchView does not filter results with ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, searchview

I have created a `listview` that has many info in one list. I tired to implement the search view in the `listview` adapter but the list do not get filtered.

Below is my source code for that Activity.

DictionaryAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.personaldictionary.R;
import com.example.personaldictionary.database.DictionaryContract;

public class DictionaryAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "DictionaryAdapter";

    public DictionaryAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }


    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"newView called cursor: "+cursor+" context: "+context+" parent: "+parent);
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.word_list, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"bindView called cursor: "+cursor+" context: "+context+" view: "+view);


        view.findViewById(R.id.container).setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.fade_scale_animation));


        TextView wordTextView = (TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.word_text_list);
        TextView wordDefTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.word_definition_list);
        TextView wordEtyloTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.word_etymologies_list);

        int wordColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD);
        int defColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_DEFINITION);
        int etyloColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_ETYMOLOGIES);


        String word = cursor.getString(wordColumnIndex);
        String wordDef = cursor.getString(defColumnIndex);
        String wordEtylo = cursor.getString(etyloColumnIndex);

        wordTextView.setText(word);
        wordDefTextView.setText(wordDef);
        wordEtyloTextView.setText(wordEtylo);


    }
}
```

**WordListActivity.java**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat;
import androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager;
import androidx.loader.content.CursorLoader;
import androidx.loader.content.Loader;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.personaldictionary.adapter.DictionaryAdapter;
import com.example.personaldictionary.database.DictionaryContract;
import com.example.personaldictionary.database.DictionaryDbHelper;

public class WordListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>  {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "WordListActivity";

    DictionaryAdapter mAdapter;
    DictionaryDbHelper mDbHelper;


    private static final int WORD_LOADER = 0;

    private String wordString;
    private String wordDefString;
    private String wordEtyloString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_word_list);

        ListView wordListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.word_list);




        View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        wordListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"productListView.setEmptyView(emptyView)");

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if(extras!=null){
            wordString = intent.getStringExtra("word");
            wordDefString = intent.getStringExtra("wordDefinition");
            wordEtyloString = intent.getStringExtra("wordEtylo");

            Log.d("WordListActivity","wordString: "+wordString+" wordDefString: "+wordDefString+" wordEtyloString: "+wordEtyloString);

            insertWord(wordString,wordDefString,wordEtyloString);

        }


        mAdapter = new DictionaryAdapter(this,null);
        wordListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(WORD_LOADER, null,this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search,menu);
        MenuItem search_item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) search_item.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                WordListActivity.this.mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    public void insertWord(String word, String word_def, String word_etylo){


        Uri newUri = null;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"insertWord() word: "+word+" word_def: "+word_def+" word_et: "+word_etylo);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD,word);
        values.put(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_DEFINITION,word_def);
        values.put(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_ETYMOLOGIES,word_etylo);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.CONTENT_URI: "+DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.CONTENT_URI);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"values: "+values);

        newUri = getContentResolver().insert(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);
        //mAdapter.swapCursor(getAllItems());

        //mAdapter.swapCursor(getAllItems());

        if (newUri == null) {
            Toast.makeText(WordListActivity.this, "Word insert error ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(WordListActivity.this, "Word insert Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    private Cursor getAllItems(){
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"getAllItems inside");
         String[] projection = {DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry._ID,
                 DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD,
                 DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_DEFINITION,
                 DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_ETYMOLOGIES};

         Cursor cursor  = getContentResolver().query(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.CONTENT_URI,projection,null,null,null);
         Log.d(LOG_TAG,"getAllItems: "+cursor);
         return cursor;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onCreateLoader called");

        String[] projection = {DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry._ID,
                DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD,
                DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_DEFINITION,
                DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_ETYMOLOGIES,};

        return new CursorLoader(this, DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.CONTENT_URI,projection,null,null,null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onLoadFinished called data: "+data);
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

activity_word_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WordListActivity"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/word_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_input" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/empty_view_title_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_subtitle_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/empty_title_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/empty_view_subtitle_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#A2AAB0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.528"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.548" />
    </RelativeLayout>




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

word_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#fff">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/card_bg"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/word_text_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/title_text_color"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/word_definition_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/word_text_list"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/word_text_list"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/word_text_list"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/content_text_color" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/word_etymologies_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/word_definition_list"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/word_definition_list"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/word_definition_list"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/content_text_color" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/word_audio"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_audio"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/container"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/container"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/container"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_gray_24dp"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

This is how the view is. I want to filter the text in blue through searchview. Could anyone suggest how to do it?

[image: View of the list]

Comment: you need to provide the ListView adapter code

Comment: updated question

Comment: This link may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44358333/adapter-getfilter-not-filtering

Comment: Thanks this helped

Answer (score 0):

You should filter list and call notifyDataSetChanged in adapter.

Example you have list ListA which contains ListA = {A,B,C}

You filter listA ( you search for item B ) FilteredList = {B}

AdapterSource = FilteredList

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

If you clear search view

AdapterSource = ListA

Comment: should I add adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() inside onQueryTextSubmit() or onQueryTextChange()????

Comment: it depends if you want to change results while typing then you can use onQueryTextChange or if you want when user click on search icon then onQueryTextSubmit. Be sure you have only filtered items inside list when calling notifyDataSetChanged. Usually I use 2 different list ( filtered list and unfiltered list )

Comment: I tried using notifyDataSetChanged in onQueryTextChange, but when I type on the search view, with every word I type the list kind of refreshes the same list and not filtered list

Comment: Every time I type I get called of onbindview from adapter but not filtered list,
Please check if there is any issue in adapter class?